# Android studio showing output of last app that i made

Tags: android, android-studio

When I am running the app, its showing the output of last app and not the current one. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try invalidate and clear cache option ?

Answer (score 0):

The "thing" which you are calling output is usually called "log" in Android and it can be seen in "Logcat".
So if you navigate to logcat in Android Studio, you could see the

- **"Device Name"** (Xiaomi Redmi 5 in the picture below),
- **"App Name"** (com.prezrohit.merchandise in the picture below),
- **"Log Type"** (Verbose in the picture below) etc (see the image below).

**You just have to select the app for which you want to see the log.**

[image]